# Entity Framework set Autogrowth and Maxsize

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a way to tell EF what to use for Autogrowth and Maxsize when it creates a database on SQL Server?

[image: Default values]

Comment: You could try running `Alter database` commands or stored procedures to change that setting using the first migration `Up()` method.

Comment: Where is that Up() method?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you can't. You can also have a look here just to be sure
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlProviderServices.cs
and on the called function (but it runs just a "create database" eventually specifing mdf and ldf file names).

Probably the best thing is that you create the database running a direct query before standard migrations.

**EDIT**
Database creation is not really automated, or better, you can decide when (and writing your migration, how) create it.
Actually I think you are using automatic migration (you did not write any code for migration).
Database is created if it does not exists and tables are created checking __MigrationHistory table (this is quite important because you can just create the DB without updating EF metadatas).
It happens before the first access to EF (at first access EF reads the mapping, check that the DB is ok and then executes the query you requested) or you can force it.
Actually I think that is more simple to decide if you need to run a create database (you can just check if it exists) than run an alter database if the parameters are wrong.

Your code could:
1. read the connection string from App/Web config
2. connect to master and not to the specified database
3. check if the database exists (select count(*) from sysdatabases where name = ...)
4. if it does not exists create it

Then you can continue with your normal code (EF will find the DB so the migrations will avoid to create it).

Comment: Database creation is entirely automated by EF. However, running an additional query after creation, like @JotaBe suggested, seems appropriate. Any more details on how to do that? I'm not too familiar with EF's migrations

Comment: I would run a query at the database creation, only once, when it is created. Is there an event, or method to override that triggers when the database is created?

Comment: But I see your point, which is to manually work around the default IDatabaseInitializer

Comment: if(Database.CreateIfNotExists()) //run the alter statement

Comment: if (!Database.Exists()) // run the create statement. Do you prefere an alter statement or a create statement? :)

Comment: I would prefer to leave the DBInitializer take care of the creation strategy, and run alter statement only when the database is created...

Answer (score 0):

Enable migrations, but not automatic migrations. [See this to learn about migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

Create the first migration. That creates an `Up()` and `Down()` method. You can see how to customize it in [Customizing migrations section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#customizing) of the previous document.

In the up method you can use `Sql("Your sql command")` to run the [ALTER DATABASE commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx) to set the growth an max size DB configuration.